# How can I merge these two left joins into a single one?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

How can I merge these two left joins: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d2954/69/0

```
SELECT d.`id`, (adcount + bdcount)
FROM `docs` d

LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT da.`doc_id`, COUNT(da.`doc_id`) AS adcount FROM `docs_scod_a` da
  INNER JOIN `scod_a` a ON a.`id` = da.`scod_a_id`
  WHERE a.`ver_a` IN ('AA', 'AB')
  GROUP BY da.`doc_id`
) ad ON ad.`doc_id` = d.`id`

LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT db.`doc_id`, COUNT(db.`doc_id`) AS bdcount FROM `docs_scod_b` db
  INNER JOIN `scod_b` b ON b.`id` = db.`scod_b_id`
  WHERE b.`ver_b` IN ('BA', 'BB')
  GROUP BY db.`doc_id`
) bd ON bd.`doc_id` = d.`id`
```

to be a Single left join just to ease its use in my code, while making it no less slower?

Comment: The two subqueries are on entirely different tables, and what you have now actually looks reasonable to me.  What is your motivation for wanting to do this, other than possibly fewer lines of code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I use `PHP` to add these extra lines, Making less use of `PHP` would be better for me, The two subqueries are in two different tables but has the same set of columns, so i thought about using `UNION ALL` but didn't work with me, If making it a single left join is valid but would make it slower, Then is there is no need to merge.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name mysql, added the tag now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first emphasize that your method of doing the calculation is the better method.  You have two separate dimensions and aggregating them separately is often the most efficient method for doing the calculation.  It is also the most scalable method.

That said, your query should be equivalent to this version:

```
SELECT d.id,
       count(distinct a.id),
       count(distinct b.id) 
FROM docs d left join
     docs_scod_a da
     ON da.doc_id = d.id LEFT JOIN
     scod_a a
     ON a.id = da.scod_a_id AND a.ver_a IN ('AA', 'AB') LEFT JOIN
     docs_scod_b db
     ON db.doc_id = d.id LEFT JOIN
     scod_b b
     ON b.id = db.scod_b_id AND b.ver_b IN ('BA', 'BB')
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY d.id;
```

This query is more expensive than it looks, because the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` incurs additional overhead compared to `COUNT()`.

And [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d2954/74) is the SQL Fiddle.

And, because `LEFT JOIN` can return `NULL` values, your query is more correctly written as:

```
SELECT d.`id`, COALESCE(adcount, 0) + COALESCE(bdcount, 0)
```

If you were having problems with the results, this small change might fix those problems.

Answer (score 1):

Performance may be a big problem, depending on sizes of each table.  It appears to be an "inflate-deflate" situation since it first "inflates" the number of rows via `JOIN`, then "deflates" via `GROUP BY`.  The formulation below avoids inflation-deflation.

But first, if I understand this subquery correctly, this

```
SELECT  da.`doc_id`, COUNT(da.`doc_id`) AS adcount
    FROM  `docs_scod_a` da
    INNER JOIN  `scod_a` a  ON a.`id` = da.`scod_a_id`
    WHERE  a.`ver_a` IN ('AA', 'AB')
    GROUP BY  da.`doc_id`
```

can be rewritten as

```
SELECT  `doc_id`, 
        ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  `scod_a` 
            WHERE `id` = da.`scod_a_id`
              AND `ver_a` IN ('AA', 'AB') 
        ) AS adcount
    FROM  `docs_scod_a` AS da
```

If that is correct, then the entire query becomes

```
SELECT  d.id, 
        ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  docs_scod_a ds
            JOIN  scod_a s  ON s.id = ds.scod_a_id
            WHERE  ds.doc_id = d.id
              AND  s.ver_a IN ('AA', 'AB') 
        ) + 
        ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  docs_scod_b ds
            JOIN  scod_b s  ON s.id = ds.scod_b_id
            WHERE  ds.doc_id = d.id
              AND  s.ver_b IN ('BA', 'BB') 
        )
    FROM  docs AS d
```

Which needs these indexes:

```
docs_scod_a:  (doc_id, scod_a_id), (scod_a_id, doc_id)
docs_scod_b:  (doc_id, scod_b_id), (scod_b_id, doc_id)
scod_a:  (ver_a, id)
scod_b:  (ver_b, id)
docs: -- presumably has  PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

Note the lack of `GROUP BY`.

`docs_scod_a` smells like a many-to-many mapping table.  I recommend you follow the tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

(No `COALESCE` is needed since `COUNT` will simply return zero.)

(I don't know whether my version is better (faster or whatever) than Gordon's, nor whether my indexes will help his formulation.)